# Delete Wordpress Title bar from page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

How can i delete title bar from any wordpress page, see picture below.
Knowing that the page is empty in edit mode.
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9deq1.jpg)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RkG9.jpg)

Thanks an advance :)

Comment: Try something like display:none; via your theme CSS (via the wordpress backoffice css editor for example). 
Or edit header.php of your theme (a child theme ideally) and remove the concerned html.

Comment: Thanks, but i guess we can delete it without modifying the css files.